# Run-time error of Spark code in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, runtime-error

Running spark code in IDEA Intellij is painful as a new Spark/Intellij user. 
I googled many pages, but didn't find a solution to this. 
Code is very simple as below. 
I'm getting run-time error in this line:
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.math.random

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
//    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
//    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 3
//    val n = 100000 * slices
//    val count = spark.parallelize(1 to n, slices).map { i =>
//      val x = random * 2 - 1
//      val y = random * 2 - 1
//      if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
//    }.reduce(_ + _)
//    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
//    val pi = 4.0 * count / n
//    val ppi = spark.parallelize(Seq(pi))
//    ppi.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/bryan/spark/output.pi")
//    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

The error message is :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\code\spark-cdh\analysis-jobs\example\target\scala-2.10\classes;C:\Users\spark39\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-compiler\jars\scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\spark39\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.4\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.spark.example.test.HelloWorld
Hello World
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at com.samsungaustin.yac.spark.example.test.HelloWorld$.main(Test.scala:15)
    at com.samsungaustin.yac.spark.example.test.HelloWorld.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Someone mentioned about adding classpath through 'Edit Configurations' menu, but can anybody tell exactly how I figure this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with new technology can often be a bit painful, but it might lead to valuable new knowledge and experience. Do you use a Maven pom.xml file for building your project? I would advise you to use Maven or something similar to keep track of which libraries your code needs.

You can also try one of the existing examples that are available for Spark on the web site: http://spark.apache.org/examples.html. There is also a GitHub repository with even more examples: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples. (This repository already has a Maven pom.xml file: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/pom.xml.)

The following page contains (hopefully) Useful Developer Tools: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools

There are also several tutorials that use Spark, Scala, and IntelliJ IDEA:

- https://medium.com/large-scale-data-processing/how-to-kick-start-spark-development-on-intellij-idea-in-4-steps-c7c8f5c2fe63#.y0uxk7gay
- https://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/Step_by_Step_instructions_on_how_to_build_Spark_App_with_IntelliJ_IDEA

Comment: I appreciate your help. Yes, it was painful .. and still painful but I'm getting familiar with it. I'm using SBT, but can refer to maven pom.xml. In my case, the problem was src setting in "Edit Configurations'.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your exploration of Spark!